# Replace ASCII characters in Python

Tags: python, pandas, ascii

I have a dataframe with bunch of URL with ASCII characters that need cleaning:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Webpage':['Webpage_A','Webpage_B','Webpage_C','Webpage_D'],\
'NSW and VIC': ['https://contentspace.global.com/teams/Australia/NSW/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?\
RootFolder=%2Fteams%Australia%2FNSW%2FDocuments%2FIn%20Scope%2FA%20I%20TOPPER%20GROUP&FolderCTID=\
0x01200016BC4CE0C21A6645950C100F37A60ABD&View=%7B64F44840%2D04FE%2D4341%2D9FAC%2D902BB54E7F10%7D',\
'https://contentspace.global.com/teams/Australia/Victoria/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder\
=%2Fteams%2FAustralia%2FVictoria%2FDocuments%2FIn%20Scope&FolderCTID=0x0120006984C27BA03D394D9E2E95FB\
893593F9&View=%7B3276A351%2D18C1%2D4D32%2DADFF%2D54158B504FCC%7D',0,0], 'Other States': [0,0,\
'https://contentspace.global.com/teams/Australia/WA/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?\
RootFolder=%2Fteams%2FAustralia%2FWA%2FDocuments%2FIn%20Scope&FolderCTID=0x012000EDE8B08D50FC3741A5\
206CD23377AB75&View=%7B287FFF9E%2DD60C%2D4401%2D9ECD%2DC402524F1D4A%7D',\
'https://contentspace.global.com/teams/Australia/QLD/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%\
2Fteams%2FAustralia%2FQLD%2FDocuments%2FIn%20Scope%2FAACO%20GROUP&FolderCTID=0x012000E689A6C1960E8\
648A90E6EC3BD899B1A&View=%7B6176AC45%2DC34C%2D4F7C%2D9027%2DDAEAD1391BFC%7D']})
```

The Output of the DataFrame looks like below:

```
    NSW and VIC                                     Other States                            Webpage
0   https://contentspace.global.com/teams/Australi...   0                                   Webpage_A
1   https://contentspace.global.com/teams/Australi...   0                                   Webpage_B
2   0                                     https://contentspace.global.com/teams/Australi... Webpage_C
3   0                                     https://contentspace.global.com/teams/Australi... Webpage_D
```

The ASCII characters to be mapped is as follows:

```
df_ASCII = pd.DataFrame({'%21': ['!'],
 '%22': ['“'],
 '%23': ['#'],
 '%24': ['$'],
 '%25': ['%'],
 '%26': ['&'],
 '%27': ['‘'],
 '%28': ['('],
 '%29': [')'],
 '%2A': ['*'],
 '%2B': ['+'],
 '%2C': [','],
 '%2D': ['–'],
 '%2E': ['.'],
 '%2F': ['/'],
 '%30': ['0'],
 '%31': ['1'],
 '%32': ['2'],
 '%33': ['3'],
 '%34': ['4'],
 '%35': ['5'],
 '%36': ['6'],
 '%37': ['7'],
 '%38': ['8'],
 '%39': ['9'],
 '%3A': [':'],
 '%3B': [';'],
 '%3C': ['<'],
 '%3D': ['='],
 '%3E': ['>'],
 '%3F': ['?'],
 '%40': ['@'],
 '%41': ['A'],
 '%42': ['B'],
 '%43': ['C'],
 '%44': ['D'],
 '%45': ['E'],
 '%46': ['F'],
 '%47': ['G'],
 '%48': ['H'],
 '%49': ['I'],
 '%4A': ['J'],
 '%4B': ['K'],
 '%4C': ['L '],
 '%4D': ['M'],
 '%4E': ['N'],
 '%4F': ['O'],
 '%50': ['P'],
 '%51': ['Q'],
 '%52': ['R'],
 '%53': ['S'],
 '%54': ['T'],
 '%55': ['U'],
 '%56': ['V'],
 '%57': ['W'],
 '%58': ['X'],
 '%59': ['Y'],
 '%5A': ['Z'],
 '%5B': ['['],
 '%5C': [nan],
 '%5D': [']'],
 '%5E': ['^'],
 '%5F': ['_'],
 '%60': ['`'],
 '%61': ['a'],
 '%62': ['b'],
 '%63': ['c'],
 '%64': ['d'],
 '%65': ['e'],
 '%66': ['f'],
 '%67': ['g'],
 '%68': ['h'],
 '%69': ['i'],
 '%6A': ['j'],
 '%6B': ['k'],
 '%6C': ['l'],
 '%6D': ['m'],
 '%6E': ['n'],
 '%6F': ['o'],
 '%70': ['p'],
 '%71': ['q'],
 '%72': ['r'],
 '%73': ['s'],
 '%74': ['t'],
 '%75': ['u'],
 '%76': ['v'],
 '%77': ['w'],
 '%78': ['x'],
 '%79': ['y'],
 '%7A': ['z'],
 '%7B': ['{'],
 '%7C': ['|'],
 '%7D': ['}'],
 '%7E': ['~'],
 '%7F': [nan],
 '%80': ['€'],
 '%81': [nan],
 '%82': ['‚'],
 '%83': ['ƒ'],
 '%84': ['„'],
 '%85': ['…'],
 '%86': ['†'],
 '%87': ['‡'],
 '%88': ['ˆ'],
 '%89': ['‰'],
 '%8A': ['Š'],
 '%8B': ['‹'],
 '%8C': ['Œ'],
 '%8D': [nan],
 '%8E': ['Ž'],
 '%8F': [nan],
 '%90': [nan],
 '%91': ['‘'],
 '%92': ['’'],
 '%93': ['“'],
 '%94': ['”'],
 '%95': ['•'],
 '%96': ['–'],
 '%97': ['—'],
 '%98': ['˜'],
 '%99': ['™'],
 '%9A': ['š'],
 '%9B': ['›'],
 '%9C': ['œ'],
 '%9D': [nan],
 '%9E': ['ž'],
 '%9F': ['Ÿ'],
 '%A0': [nan],
 '%A1': ['¡'],
 '%A2': ['¢'],
 '%A3': ['£'],
 '%A4': [nan],
 '%A5': ['¥'],
 '%A6': ['|'],
 '%A7': ['§'],
 '%A8': ['¨'],
 '%A9': ['©'],
 '%AA': ['ª'],
 '%AB': ['«'],
 '%AC': ['¬'],
 '%AD': ['¯'],
 '%AE': ['®'],
 '%AF': ['¯'],
 '%B0': ['°'],
 '%B1': ['±'],
 '%B2': ['²'],
 '%B3': ['³'],
 '%B4': ['´'],
 '%B5': ['µ'],
 '%B6': ['¶'],
 '%B7': ['·'],
 '%B8': ['¸'],
 '%B9': ['¹'],
 '%BA': ['º'],
 '%BB': ['»'],
 '%BC': ['¼'],
 '%BD': ['½'],
 '%BE': ['¾'],
 '%BF': ['¿'],
 '%C0': ['À'],
 '%C1': ['Á'],
 '%C2': [nan],
 '%C3': ['Ã'],
 '%C4': ['Ä'],
 '%C5': ['Å'],
 '%C6': ['Æ'],
 '%C7': ['Ç'],
 '%C8': ['È'],
 '%C9': ['É'],
 '%CA': [nan],
 '%CB': ['Ë'],
 '%CC': ['Ì'],
 '%CD': ['Í'],
 '%CE': ['Î'],
 '%CF': ['Ï'],
 '%D0': ['Ð'],
 '%D1': ['Ñ'],
 '%D2': ['Ò'],
 '%D3': ['Ó'],
 '%D4': ['Ô'],
 '%D5': ['Õ'],
 '%D6': ['Ö'],
 '%D7': [nan],
 '%D8': ['Ø'],
 '%D9': ['Ù'],
 '%DA': ['Ú'],
 '%DB': ['Û'],
 '%DC': ['Ü'],
 '%DD': ['Ý'],
 '%DE': ['Þ'],
 '%DF': ['ß'],
 '%E0': ['à'],
 '%E1': ['á'],
 '%E2': ['â'],
 '%E3': ['ã'],
 '%E4': ['ä'],
 '%E5': ['å'],
 '%E6': ['æ'],
 '%E7': ['ç'],
 '%E8': ['è'],
 '%E9': ['é'],
 '%EA': ['ê'],
 '%EB': ['ë'],
 '%EC': ['ì'],
 '%ED': ['í'],
 '%EE': ['î'],
 '%EF': ['ï'],
 '%F0': ['ð'],
 '%F1': ['ñ'],
 '%F2': ['ò'],
 '%F3': ['ó'],
 '%F4': ['ô'],
 '%F5': ['õ'],
 '%F6': ['ö'],
 '%F7': ['÷'],
 '%F8': ['ø'],
 '%F9': ['ù'],
 '%FA': ['ú'],
 '%FB': ['û'],
 '%FC': ['ü'],
 '%FD': ['ý'],
 '%FE': ['þ'],
 '%FF': ['ÿ']})
```

I tried to replace them one-by-one (as below), which worked perfectly with no issue, but I can't seem to be able to get the full ASCII mapping to work even though I tried to convert it to either a list or dictionary:

```
cols = ['NSW and VIC', 'Other States']

for i in cols:  
    df[i] = df[i].str.replace('%2F','/')
```

So the question is: How can I clean up all the ASCII characters in multiple columns in df?

Comment: You should probably use `urllib` like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50837799/567595

Comment: Your mapping table seems incomplete. Which specific character set should this map into?

Comment: May I be pedantic and point out that this is *extended* ASCII. Strictly speaking the ASCII table is 127 characters and stops at hex code 7F.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much simpler solution. You can decode the url using [`urllib.parse.unquote()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote).

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
df["NSW and VIC"] = df["NSW and VIC"].apply(lambda x: unquote(x) if(x!=0) else x)
df['Other States'] = df["Other States"].apply(lambda x: unquote(x) if(x!=0) else x)
df
```

**Output:**

```
>>> df['NSW and VIC'][1]
'https://contentspace.global.com/teams/Australia/Victoria/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=/teams/Australia/Victoria/Documents/In Scope&FolderCTID=0x0120006984C27BA03D394D9E2E95FB893593F9&View={3276A351-18C1-4D32-ADFF-54158B504FCC}'
```